# Xcode 7.3.1 app submission to the Appstore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Does Apple still accept apps built using `Xcode 7.3.1` (`Swift 2.2`) for the **AppStore** ?

Or does it have to be migrated to `Xcode 8` (at least `Swift 2.3` or above) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you're still able to upload apps built with Xcode 7.3.1, **but** you have to use:

- Xcode 8.0 or higher

or

- Application Loader 3.6 or higher (bundled with Xcode 8)

for the upload process.

This was after the public release of Xcode 8 and the app was accepted for submisson.
Tested on Mac OS Sierra (10.12.1)

Comment: So you submitted an app built using Xcode 7.3.1 but used Xcode 8 to upload it and the app was approved by Apple ?

Comment: Yes sir, that's how I did it. And I had the same reason (Swift 2.2 codebase)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Apple still accept.
If it doesn't work in default way (archive, then upload to AppStore), try to export .ipa file and upload it via Application Loader.

Comment: Have you submitted using Xcode 7.3.1 and has it been approved by Apple for App store submission ?

Comment: yes, yesterday apple approved app submitted from Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Yes, Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2. I had only one problem and it was resolved with application loader